# Running SQL query returns error in SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, database, magento

I tried inputting the below script that was asked of the developer to run. Thus, completing the deletion of a `magento` module. But I keep getting a return error.

MySQL said:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE `eav_attribute` attribute_code = 'tipo_pessoa'' at line 3
>   ?

I am trying to run..

```js
   

 >DELETE FROM `core_resource` WHERE CODE = 'idecheckoutvm_setup';

>DELETE FROM WHERE `eav_attribute` attribute_code = 'tipo_pessoa'; 
>DELETE FROM WHERE `eav_attribute` attribute_code = 'rg'; 
>DELETE FROM WHERE `eav_attribute` attribute_code = 'razao_social'; 
>DELETE FROM WHERE `eav_attribute` attribute_code = 'nome_fantasia'; 
>DELETE FROM WHERE `eav_attribute` attribute_code = 'insc_est'; 
>DELETE FROM WHERE `eav_attribute` attribute_code = 'mobile';
>
>ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN `sales_flat_order` customer_tipo_pessoa; 
>ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote` customer_tipo_pessoa DROP COLUMN;
>
>ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order` customer_razao_social DROP COLUMN, 
>ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote` customer_razao_social DROP COLUMN;
>
>ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN `sales_flat_order` customer_nome_fantasia; 
>ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN `sales_flat_quote` customer_nome_fantasia;
>
>ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN `sales_flat_order` customer_rg; 
>ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN `sales_flat_quote` customer_rg;
>
>ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN `sales_flat_order` customer_insc_est; 
>ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN `sales_flat_quote` customer_insc_est;
>
>ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN `sales_flat_order_address` mobile; 
>ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN `sales_flat_quote_address` mobile;
>
>DELETE FROM `core_config_data` WHERE path LIKE '% idecheckoutvm%';
```

on

> Server: Localhost via UNIX socket Software: Percona Server Software
>   version: 5.5.40-36.1 - Percona Server (GPL), Release 36.1, Revision
>   707 Protocol version: 10

Comment: DELETE FROM ??? Where...What is the table name

Answer (score 3):

```
DELETE FROM WHERE eav_attribute
```

Yeah, delete but from where actually? you are missing the table name

```
DELETE FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE  attribute_code = 'tipo_pessoa';
             ^              ^
```

Same for

```
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN     // Alter which table?
```

All but a couple of your queries are missing that.

Comment: Thanks everyone, seems to have cleared that up. However, the Alter Table Drop Column is changed to which format?

Comment: Similar to others. `ALTER TABLE yourTableName DROP COLUMN columnName`

Answer (score 0):

Should there be a "." between these ? The missing table name (multiple) suggests a "replace" edit has occured ?

Answer (score 0):

Change

> DELETE FROM WHERE eav_attribute ....

to

> DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE .....

Answer (score 0):

You have your delete syntax muddled up. It should be `delete from table where ...` and not `delete from where table ...`.

So, e.g., instead of:

```
DELETE FROM WHERE eav_attribute attribute_code = 'tipo_pessoa';
```

You should have:

```
DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'tipo_pessoa';
```

The same goes for the rest of your delete statements.

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax for delete statement is:

```
Delete from <table_name> where ....
```

Your statement reads:

```
DELETE FROM WHERE eav_attribute attribute_code = 'tipo_pessoa';
```

You are missing table name after "FROM"

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU GUYS.
RAN THE EDITS AND EVERYTHING RAN SMOOTHLY.
Here is the final changes for those curious.

Thanks again.

```js
DELETE FROM `core_resource` WHERE CODE = 'idecheckoutvm_setup';

DELETE FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE attribute_code = 'tipo_pessoa';
DELETE FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE attribute_code = 'rg';
DELETE FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE attribute_code = 'razao_social';
DELETE FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE attribute_code = 'nome_fantasia';
DELETE FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE attribute_code = 'insc_est';
DELETE FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE attribute_code = 'mobile';

ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order` DROP COLUMN customer_tipo_pessoa;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote` DROP COLUMN customer_tipo_pessoa;

ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order` DROP COLUMN customer_razao_social;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote` DROP COLUMN customer_razao_social;

ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order` DROP COLUMN customer_nome_fantasia;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote` DROP COLUMN customer_nome_fantasia;

ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order` DROP COLUMN customer_rg;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote` DROP COLUMN customer_rg;

ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order` DROP COLUMN customer_insc_est;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote` DROP COLUMN customer_insc_est;

ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_address` DROP COLUMN mobile;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address` DROP COLUMN mobile;

DELETE FROM `core_config_data` WHERE path LIKE '%idecheckoutvm%';
```